# How to access conjunction data message data?

Tags: spacecraft, space-track

I have a Space-Track account, however, the public CDM's only have an ID and basic information about the two spacecraft, but nothing about their covariances or orbital information. Is there any way to download recent identified CDM information or is this considered proprietary? Are there other websites out there that store CDMs?

Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 2):

CDMs on space-track.org are archived 72 hours after TCA. For basic orbital elements you should be able to pull the TLE for the secondary object identified in the conjunction. However, currently there are no products available with covariance values.